# ayuda con autocomplete en elementos creados dinamicamente

Tags: c#, jquery, mvc, razor

Recurro a ustedes debido a que no he podido implementar el autocomplete en elementos creados dinamicamente con jquery lo hago de la siguiente manera.

```
$('#addMarcaTabla').click(function () {       
    var html = '';
    html += '<tr class="itemMarcasAgregadas">';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control denominacion" placeholder="Marca /Den. Distintiva"/><span class="error">Es Requerido</span></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control registroSanitario" placeholder="Núm. Registro Sanitario"/></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control rfcTitular searchInput" placeholder="Titular Registro Sanitario"/></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control procedencia" placeholder="Procedencia"/></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control fabricante" onBlur="GetRazonSocial(this);"  placeholder="Fabricante"/></td>';
    html += '<td><button type="button" name="removeMarcaTemp" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm removeMarcaTemp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('#tblMarcasTemp').append(html);
    itemMarca = itemMarca + 1;
    if (itemMarca != 0)
    {
        $('#submit').show();
    }               
});
```

y mi evento para poder agregar el evento al input con la clase searchInput es el siguiente.

```
$('.searchInput').autocomplete({
    source: _urlBase + "Ofertas/GetProcedimientos",
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#MtoProveedorId").empty();
        GetProveedoresConOferta(ui.item.id);
        id = (ui.item.id);
        $("#MtoProcedimientoId").val(ui.item.id);
    }
})
```

sin embargo no me muestra ningun error pero tampoco muestra los resultados.

Comment: ¿La instrucción en la que defines el autocomplete se ejecuta después de crear los elementos?

Comment: si la instrucción autocomplete lo pongo después de crear el elemento

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: que tal si lo soluciones y esta funcionando. saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Los métodos que se mandan llamar desde el selector están visibles solo para lo creado en el **dom** en ese momento

```
$('.searchInput').autocomplete(function (e) { });
```

Debes poner tu funcion callback de los objetos dinámicos en *document* no en el *selector*

```
$(document).on('autocomplete', '.searchInput', function (e) { });
```